# Linq grouping and nested grouping

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

I am in the process of creating a `TreeView` that can be displayed with various groupings. The essential classes are below:

```
public class MachineStatus 
{
  public string MachineName {get;set;} 
  public string Department {get;set;}
  public string LocationName {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<DeviceStatus> Devices {get;set;}
}

public class DeviceStatus
{
  public string DeviceName {get;set;}
  public string DeviceType {get;set;}
  public string IpAddress {get;set;}
  public ConnectionStatus Status {get;set;}
}
```

The groups would be by `Department`, by `Location`, and by `DeviceType`. The first two are easy with Linq. However, `DeviceType` is challenging because each `Machine` may contain multiple `Device` objects with different types.

**Raw Data**

```
Machine 1
  |__ Device A (Type Foo)
  |__ Device B (Type Bar)
Machine 2
  |__ Device C (Type Foo)
  |__ Device D (Type Zed)
```

**Result**

```
Type Bar
  |__ Machine 1
      |__Device B
Type Foo
  |__Machine 1
      |__Device A
  |__Machine 2
      |__Device C
Type Zed
  |__Machine 2
      |__Device D
```

I'm thinking I'd have to flatten the list of `MachineStatus` records before trying to group but I'm getting mixed up in using SelectMany...

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer..?

Comment: Yeah, I did, I am in the process of integrating it. I wanted to look into a few things before marking it as an answer (really just to add some comments for future folks who may need this). Integrating anonymous types into a tree view is...not fun :) I'll update tonight.

Comment: From your result data it appears that you are grouping devices by machine name as well as type - so two-level nested grouping. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) & [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:-

```
var result = machines.SelectMany(x => x.Devices, 
                                    (machineObj, devices) => new { machineObj, devices })
                     .GroupBy(x => new { x.devices.DeviceType, x.machineObj.Department, 
                                                             x.machineObj.LocationName })
                     .Select(x => new
                                 {
                                     DeviceType = x.Key.DeviceType,
                                     Department = x.Key.Department,
                                     Location = x.Key.LocationName,
                                     machines = x
                                 });
```

Here is the Complete [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5gMk2) with sample data I have used and following is the output for same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        DeviceStatus deviceA = new DeviceStatus() { DeviceName = "A", DeviceType = "foo" };
        DeviceStatus deviceB = new DeviceStatus() { DeviceName = "B", DeviceType = "bar" };
        DeviceStatus deviceC = new DeviceStatus() { DeviceName = "C", DeviceType = "foo" };
        DeviceStatus deviceD = new DeviceStatus() { DeviceName = "D", DeviceType = "zed" };


        MachineStatus status1 = new MachineStatus() { MachineName = "1", Department = "1", LocationName = "1", Devices = new List<DeviceStatus>{ deviceA, deviceB} };
        MachineStatus status2 = new MachineStatus() { MachineName = "2", Department = "2", LocationName = "2", Devices = new List<DeviceStatus> { deviceC, deviceD } };

        List<MachineStatus> machines = new List<MachineStatus>() { status1, status2};

        var result = machines.SelectMany(x => x.Devices, (a, b) => new { DeviceType = b.DeviceType, MachineName = a.MachineName, DeviceName = b.DeviceName } );
        var result2 = result.GroupBy(x => new {x.DeviceType}).Select( z => new { DeviceType = z.Key.DeviceType, Machines = z.ToList().GroupBy(y => y.MachineName) });

        foreach (var group1 in result2)
        {
            foreach (var group2 in group1.Machines)
            {
                foreach (var group3 in group2)
                {
                    Console.Write(group1.DeviceType + ":");
                    Console.Write(group3.MachineName + ":");
                    Console.WriteLine(group3.DeviceName);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public class MachineStatus
    {
        public string MachineName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DeviceStatus> Devices { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceStatus
    {
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        public ConnectionStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConnectionStatus
    {
    }
}
}
```

Produced the following output:

foo:1:A
foo:2:C
bar:1:B
zed:2:D

Which is grouped as:

foo:1:A
foo:2:C

bar:1:B

zed:2:D

Comment: Note: The output is 4 entries as grouped in the original question.  This is the exact expected output (not 5)